# Is it ok to post a picture of an insect to ask what it is?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I took a few pictures of an insect last night, and I really have no idea what it is, and am very curious to find out. Would it be off topic to post it as a question to see if anyone else can possibly classify it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it would be off topic, but you can always hop into Chat and ask there. The room is persistent so even if there's no one there they will see it when they join later.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely off-topic.

There are, however, [several "what's that bug" sites on the internet](https://encrypted.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=what%27s%20that%20bug&btnG=Search) you could turn to.

On-topic would be: "How can I take a better picture of this bug, whatever it is?"

On-topic would *also* be: "I came across this daguerreotype of an insect. Is the photographer known, and what was the historical importance of this artist, image, and technique?"

Comment: That last part is kind of a whole other thing.

Comment: Well, so is the next-to-last part, yeah?

Comment: Uhh, right....?

Comment: "_How can I take a better picture of this bug?_" - doesn't this fall under photo critique, which is off-topic according to FAQ?

Comment: Critique is off-topic, but asking for technique improvements with an example photo is on-topic.

Comment: I would say that's _constructive_ critique. The [discussion linked from FAQ](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/150/should-photo-critiques-be-allowed) asks to be more specific about desired results. And we recently voted [a similar question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15381/how-to-get-started-with-portraits) closed.